# How to create a composite key of one foreign key and one primary key Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot to build an API. It is an API for a punishment system. Within the database there are two tables used for rules, these are the Rules table and the Community table.
[image]

The rule Id is an integer and the community Id is a foreign key from the communities table. There is expected to be 0, 1 or Many rules for a community while a rule is made by exactly one community.

This is the behaviour I'm looking to replicate in my Spring Boot application.

So far I have the following code:

Community.java

```
@Entity // Maps to database
public class Community {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

Rule.java

```
@Entity // Maps to database
public class Rule {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RuleId ruleId;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String description;
```

RuleId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class RuleId implements Serializable {

    private UUID communityId;
    private Integer ruleId;

    public RuleId(UUID communityId, Integer ruleId) {
        this.communityId = communityId;
        this.ruleId = ruleId;
    }
```

I have read through some threads on stack already which is where I have the embedded idea from but I am still confused about how I would get this to work with my scenario. Any help is greatly appreciated just to clear this confusion up.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by taking the one to one relationship from Zukaru's answer.

What I wanted was a composite key comprised from `community_id` and `rule_id`. Community Id is a foreign key to the primary key on the `Communities` table.

To implement this I had 2 classes. `Rule` and `RulePrimaryData`.

Rule.java

```
@Entity // Maps to database
@Table(name = "rules")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Rule {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RulePrimaryData id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "community_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "community_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Community communities;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    public Rule(RulePrimaryData ruleId, String description) {
        this.id = ruleId;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

An embedded Id was used to make the composite key containing the UUID and Integer.

RulePrimaryData.java

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data //Getters, setters, constructors
public class RulePrimaryData implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "community_id_fk", nullable = false)
    private UUID communityId;

    @Column(name = "rule_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer ruleId;

    public RulePrimaryData(UUID communityId, int ruleId) {
        this.communityId = communityId;
        this.ruleId = ruleId;
    }
}
```

Finally, the relationship was a One to One which I initially thought was a Many to One. In the definition I joined the `community_id_fk` column from the EmbeddedId to the `community_id` column in the Communities table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation `@JoinColumn(...)` and specify the relationship, in your case: `@OneToOne(...)`

Then you can simply define your `Rule` entity with only `Long id` or `int id` and as:

```
@Entity
public class Rule {
    
    @Id // map as id field
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // Auto generate id when update db
    @Column(name = "Rule_Id") // map the column field
    private Long ruleId;
    
    // Simply add annotation to map foreign key
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "community_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "community_id")
    private Community community;    

    // more field ...
    @Column(name = "description", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String description;
}
```

For More guide you can see https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Comment: Does this mean my primary key is a composite key of ruleId and communityId? Because the ruleId can be reused for each community that has a set of say 1 to 10 rules. The community Id is what will make the record unique for each rule.